# How can I completely remove active tab indicator in tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, tabs, android-viewpager

The design I want:

[image]

The one I tried:

[image]

XML code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_group"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tab_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:tabStripEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb_gruop"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_tab_selector"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicator="@null"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingTop="-20dp"
    app:tabPaddingBottom="-20dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabRippleColor="@null"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance">
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

bg_tab_background:

[image]

bg_tab_selector:

[image]

Comment: Add `bg_tab_selector` and `bg_tab_background` with question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"` this should help as it will reduce the tabIndicator's height